# :hover:after css tooltip and white-space issue

Tags: css, html

the scenario is described here:

```css
.mainbox{
    width:150px;
}
.container{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.position1{
    display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 2px;
 background-color: #B6DEFC;
 border: 1px solid;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-color: #A8A8A8;
 position: relative;
 font-size: xx-small;
 cursor: pointer;
 white-space: normal;
}
.position1:hover:after{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 content: attr(data-title);
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
 padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
 background: #FF9999;
 border-radius:5px;
 z-index: 1000;
 font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
<div class="container">
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title1"></div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title2"></div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title3"></div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like the tooltip (:hover:after) to show up out of the **container** and the **mainbox**. I think it's a white-space issue...

Can someone help me in solving this?

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.position1:hover, .position1:after{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    content: attr(data-title);
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
    background: #FF9999;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: small;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

update:

You can try solution like this, remove `position:relative` from `.position1`, then apply this rule (`position:relative`) to `.mainbox` , in this case the tooltips will be relative to the element which is outside of the element with rule `overflow-x:hidden` and will be visible.  I have update also the code, run it again

there is no problem with white space, the container set as `overflow:hidden` you can't show the tooltips  out of the container

```css
.mainbox{
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.container{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.position1{
    display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 2px;
 background-color: #B6DEFC;
 border: 1px solid;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-color: #A8A8A8;
 /*position: relative;*/
 font-size: xx-small;
 cursor: pointer;
 white-space: normal;
}
.position1:hover:after{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 content: attr(data-title);
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
 padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
 background: #FF9999;
 border-radius:5px;
 z-index: 1000;
 font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
<div class="container">
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title1"></div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title2"></div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title3"></div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, there will be need think... I will update answer, as I find any solutuion

Answer (score 0):

Now i understand what exactly you want after seeing the image.

You just change position absolute to fixed in .position1:hover:after class and here is the updated fiddle.

```
.mainbox{
    width:250px;
    position:relative;
}
.container{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.position1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #B6DEFC;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #A8A8A8;
    position: relative;
    font-size: xx-small;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
.position1:hover:after{
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
    background: #FF9999;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: small;
}
.number{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    padding:1px;   
}
.name{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 41px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}
.date{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: can you please attach any snap that what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: sure: [Image](http://i59.tinypic.com/zmcbys.png); I also prepared a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q19kctve/2/)

Comment: Wow...it seems to work...but... if you change `.mainbox{
    width:250px;
    position:relative;
}` in `.mainbox{
    width:25%;
    position:relative;
}` the effect is awful :( any ideas concerning this? :) [Fiddle bis](http://jsfiddle.net/q19kctve/5/)

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q19kctve/8/) This is the best that i can achieve as per your requirement. In this i have done some changes in the html and css. i have introduced another span with tooltipval class in every position1 div and i have removed ".position1:hover:after" class from css and added some other classes (i have used [Css3 Tooltip](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css3-tooltip) to create tooltip and done some changes on it according to your requirement). it is mandatory  to give space at left of mainbox for the tooltips of left most boxes. if it works than please tick the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sarhov...
even I don't like the "effect" (I mean, look at box 3 and 4, and its tooltip: they show up very far from the box)... I can't "touch" the relative positioning in **position1** class.

the reason is the following...I compleate the code above with this...

I need to put labels in the boxes like these:

```
<!--  HTML -->
<div class="mainbox">
<div class="container">
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title1">
        <span class="number">1</span>
        <span class="name">Name 1</span>
        <span class="date">2014/10/03</span>
    </div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title2">
        <span class="number">2</span>
        <span class="name">Name 2</span>
        <span class="date">2014/10/03</span>
    </div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title3">
        <span class="number">3</span>
        <span class="name">Name 3</span>
        <span class="date">2014/10/03</span>
    </div>
    <div class="position1" data-title="My data-title4">
        <span class="number">4</span>
        <span class="name">Name 4</span>
        <span class="date">2014/10/03</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
.mainbox{
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.container{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.position1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #B6DEFC;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #A8A8A8;
    position: relative;
    font-size: xx-small;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
.position1:hover:after{
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
    background: #FF9999;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: small;
}
.number{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    padding:1px;   
}
.name{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 41px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   
}
.date{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q19kctve/)

suggestions?

P.s.: the code is generated server-side (it's a C#/.net WebApp)